# Using C#/C++, is it possible to limit network traffic?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, networking, sockets

I'm developing a parental monitoring/tracking application that has a feature to lock down all internet activity.  While disabling the network adapter would seem like a simple solution, the application **must** have the ability to turn the internet back on remotely -- so the network needs to remain enabled, to a certain limit.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a suitable way to achieve this in practice.  Without this feature, the application is <strike>pretty much</strike> dead in the water.  So I've hit a huge road block, and I'm open to **any** suggestions.

With my application, I need to achieve two requirements:

1. Drop all internet activity. *and then*
2. Turn on only internet activity to a specified port and IP address. (my service, which will be polled)

Simple goal, right?  Not so much lately.

While I am looking to achieve this in C#, I understand that may be a long-shot and I am open to C++ solutions that could be called as a resource through my application.

Also note, I cannot install any third-party software on the user's system, as this solution needs to be all-encompassing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to inject a custom layer into the IP stack, using [Windows Filtering Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366510(VS.85).aspx). This SDK targets specifically parental control programs and such. Needless to say, as any kernel module, it has to be developed in C and you must have expert knowledge of Windows internals:

> The Windows Filtering Platform API is
>   designed for use by programmers using
>   C/C++ development software.
>   Programmers should be familiar with
>   networking concepts and design of
>   systems using user-mode and
>   kernel-mode components.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and give this a shot.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to utilize the WinINET API to achieve this; WinINET defines the basic internet settings for most/many Windows applications and can be used to define proxy information.  With this in mind you might be able to create a proxy which rejects all requests except for you messages.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but this sort of things is usually done out-of-band with [serial connection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port) or with a second NIC connected to a "trusted" LAN.