# How to limit processes bandwidth?

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming

I am doing a project which require to track a processes exactly same as task manager and limit the bandwidth of the certain processes that I choose. I try to look for the coding in C#, but only can find the capture processes coding. I want to do something similar like NetLimiter or NetBalancer. Can anyone show me code or example ? Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically limit bandwidth usage of my c# windows forms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847422/how-to-programatically-limit-bandwidth-usage-of-my-c-sharp-windows-forms-applica)

Comment: @GrawCube I have checked the topic you gave, it only talking about bandwidth, and someone giving the throtling for webpage or download manager sample. It didn't help on me. I hope you can cancel the duplicate.

Comment: So you want to throttle _another_ application's net usage?

Comment: @GrawCube I want to control download/upload any process that show in Task Manager. Thank You.

Comment: You might benefit from these two questions: [_Using C#/C++, is it possible to limit network traffic?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142906/using-c-c-is-it-possible-to-limit-network-traffic) and [_How can can I throttle bandwidth on an application domain level in Windows (in user mode)?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514288/how-can-can-i-throttle-bandwidth-on-an-application-domain-level-in-windows-in-u)